# "Last message received" as a noun

Tags: grammar

(In a computer program) I have a variable named:

```
  last_message_received
```

which represents a message. I know the phrase "Last message received" can be interpreted as an event (the last message was received) but what I want to know is if it could also be interpreted as a noun (a message) or should I definitely rename the variable as last_received_message?

Comment: There are no rules in English (or in programming languages either) for the grammatical form of variable names, so this is really off topic; but if there were such a rule, this would be fine: "[The last message received] arrived at 4:36 pm."

Comment: @Julian If you want advice on what to name your variables, you should ask your programming team or post this on one of the programming-related sites. (Although not SO, this would probably get closed there.)  My two cents: that could either mean the state of having received the message, or the message itself.

Comment: @AaronBrown: While I mentioned the variable name to give some context, this is not a question about variable naming. What I want to know is this: could the phrase "Last message received" be interpreted as a noun (the last message that was received) or not? The question was answered in the comments, so, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this is clearly a question about how English speaking programmers are going to read the name--which is to say a question about English and perfectly appropriate here.

Comment: Being a software enginner, that variable name is very common in code and completely understandable.  Nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: "last_message_received" is a single variable name (because of the underscores). Whether it is a noun or not is irrelevant without context. To write it out as three words (last message received) would make it 3 variables (without making this a programming question).

Comment: Julian, please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. For info about why this is helpful, please see [“Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)”](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: Please don't closevote this question. It's about _using English_ to name a variable. A good answer would explain the different meanings of past participles and the cues that fluent speakers use to sort them out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on Programmers Se

Comment: Actually I disagree that word order is irrelevant in program variables.  One aspect of writing good code is to write readable code and while most grammar rules don't apply,  choosing the right words in the right order is important.  The hardest code I've ever had to maintain was written by a very talented French programmer.  It was good code, it was just that my French was poor ;) @DCShannon

Comment: You're mistaken @DCShannon. The ideal is to have someone who doesn't know the programming language be able to read a line and understand conceptually what it's doing.  LastReceivedMessage = MessageQueue.MostRecent (); The best way to do that is to use the language conventions and vocabulary that people already know.

Comment: @DCShannon Writing readable code doesn't preclude the use of comments,  it's in addition to. Why use comments to explain something that is obvious if you chose meaningful variable, class, and function names?  Regardless, this question is about the interpretation of an English phrase regardless of whether it's got underscores between the words so it can be used as a variable name. It cam be answered without knowing anything about programming.

Comment: I regret having mentioned the variable-naming aspect of my question as it drew attention away from the central issue. @DCShannon: let me repeat that this is not about variable naming nor coding conventions. My coding conventions are clear; variables refering to data objects should be read as nouns in English. It was in that context that I faced some English language-related doubts, given that I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @Julian If you're asking whether a variable name is going to be interpreted as a noun in English, which is still what I understand you to be asking, then you're asking about variable naming.

Comment: @user3169 - Underscores stand for spaces in variable names. Hence, I believe the question is on topic here. Had the O.P. asked, "I know 'last received message' can be interpreted as a noun phrase, but what about 'last message received'?" that would have been fine. That's essentially the crux of this question, with the context being a variable name. I don't usually like variable-name questions on ELL, but this one strikes me as carefully crafted to be more about English than it is about the naming of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that can certainly be a noun phrase, with 'last' and 'received' both being adjectives modifying the noun 'message'.

Context would be needed to determine whether the phrase meant the message or the receipt.

In the programming context, it would be read as a reference to the event if the variable type were boolean or a date.  If it is a text or blob or something like that, then it would be understood as a noun, the message itself.

If you want to be unambiguous, your last_received_message is a better alternative.

Comment: +1 for the comments relevant to the programming context.

Comment: It's kind of absurd to consider a variable name without any context or even a data type. last_received_message could be a message about the last thing received, or the last message that was received, or a message about the last message received, or a boolean that says whether the last thing that was received was a message, versus the surrounding last_recieved_request, last_received_heartbeat or any of a million other things.

Comment: @DCShannon I agree that a variable name without context can be ambiguous, and there is not too much you can do about that. But, if your coding conventions are clear, you can at least avoid being contradictory or inconsistent. All I wanted was to know if the given sequence of words could indeed be interpreted as a noun in English (as coding conventions demand) irrespective of any other possible (and valid) interpretations a reader could have.

Comment: @DCShannon - I have no problem with an English learner asking about whether or not a three-word phrase sounds like a noun, or sounds like a verb. This site was designed for learners who know English only as a second or third language to ask native speakers questions. The only thing I see as "kind of absurd" here is the way everyone is up in arms about the fact this happens to be about a variable name. At least the O.P. carefully explained the context, which is more than can be said for a lot of the questions we get around here.